# Resizing picture with PHP?

Tags: php, image

I need to resize a picture to a fixed size. But it doesn't work and have error, what do i do?

ONLINE DEMO: http://codepad.org/3OrIHfoy

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() on line
>   58

PHP:

```
<?php
function thumbnail_box($img, $box_w, $box_h) {
    //create the image, of the required size
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($box_w, $box_h);
    if($new === false) {
        //creation failed -- probably not enough memory
        return null;
    }


    //Fill the image with a light grey color
    //(this will be visible in the padding around the image,
    //if the aspect ratios of the image and the thumbnail do not match)
    //Replace this with any color you want, or comment it out for black.
    //I used grey for testing =)
    $fill = imagecolorallocate($new, 200, 200, 205);
    imagefill($new, 0, 0, $fill);

    //compute resize ratio
    $hratio = $box_h / imagesy($img);
    $wratio = $box_w / imagesx($img);
    $ratio = min($hratio, $wratio);

    //if the source is smaller than the thumbnail size, 
    //don't resize -- add a margin instead
    //(that is, dont magnify images)
    if($ratio > 1.0)
        $ratio = 1.0;

    //compute sizes
    $sy = floor(imagesy($img) * $ratio);
    $sx = floor(imagesx($img) * $ratio);

    //compute margins
    //Using these margins centers the image in the thumbnail.
    //If you always want the image to the top left, 
    //set both of these to 0
    $m_y = floor(($box_h - $sy) / 2);
    $m_x = floor(($box_w - $sx) / 2);

    //Copy the image data, and resample
    //
    //If you want a fast and ugly thumbnail,
    //replace imagecopyresampled with imagecopyresized
    if(!imagecopyresampled($new, $img,
        $m_x, $m_y, //dest x, y (margins)
        0, 0, //src x, y (0,0 means top left)
        $sx, $sy,//dest w, h (resample to this size (computed above)
        imagesx($img), imagesy($img)) //src w, h (the full size of the original)
    ) {
        //copy failed
        imagedestroy($new);
        return null;
    }
    //copy successful
    return $new;
}
$i = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://techstroke.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/image2.png");
$thumb = thumbnail_box($i, 210, 150);
imagedestroy($i);

if(is_null($thumb)) {
    /* image creation or copying failed */
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit();
}
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Comment: I like that you're trying to use imagecreatefrom**jpeg** to load a PNG.  Good times.  Either way it looks like you don't have the php5-gd package installed for your distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() on line 58
```

`imagecreatefromjpeg()` is not callable because it does not exist. This means that the GD library has yet to be installed on your system.

[here are the installation notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php). you'll need them to get everything going. since you snagged that php function off the internet, it should work okay once you get the GD library installed.